# Unable to fetch updated records from API call after first hit(Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I used following code to hit the API call and fetch records from the server in windows phone 8.1 winRT App, Records get properly at first time but from second time onward its not returning the updated records its just return the old records only but when I closed my windows phone app and again hit the same API its returning the updated records.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Utility.managePaymentBeneficiary);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sessionID", AppContext.CurrentAppContext().UserContext.sessionID);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("deviceID", CommonFunction.GetDeviceID());
                var request = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();                    
                if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    getpaymentbeneficiaries = JSONHelper.Deserialize<PaymentBeneficiaryModel>(response);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of cache of get method
we need to use IfModifiedSince property as below got get method to refresh the data in API calls

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;